# forEach on IE10 not working on Server 2008, but works on IE10 everywhere else

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, foreach

Is there any reason why the javascript function [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would not work on IE10 when running on Windows Server 2008, when it works on all other installations of IE10 that I have available (including on [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com))?

I'm in the middle of a remote-desktop upgrade on the test site for a client - and as it's a test site the client refuses to allow external http access.  So the only web-access I have is using IE10 that is on the actual server itself (I am unable to upgrade the browser, as it's not my server).

I'm using the [sortable.js](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) library to implement simple sorting (unfortunately due to infrastructure issues, jquery is not available)... but IE10 on Windows Server 2008 throws the following error...

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

This error has added at least an hour to the upgrade (as I'm having to manually change sort orders in the database, rather than via the tools I have written)... and I'm only half way through.

The version on the server is **identical** to that on Browser Stack (10.0.9200.17566)... so I simply don't understand why it's not working.

Can anybody explain why this is happening - and more importantly if there is any way of fixing it (that doesn't involve changing the external javacsript library)?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? Nah, I didn't think so. The wonderful anonymity of SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could IE10 be running in an older document mode (maybe in compatibility view)? The forEach function isn't defined in IE7 or IE8 mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will check when I'm back at my desk in the morning

Comment: Absolutely spot on - never even considered compatibility mode.  For anybody else finding this, the compatibility mode on IE10 is accessed through the F12 developer tools ([here are instructions](http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/) on how to turn compatibility mode **on**, so you can use the same to turn off)